# How can I extract subarrays with the same index from a large array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list that has the following format:

```
[ [[John],[Sam],[Jack]], [[Student],[Athlete],[Teacher]],[[1],[2],[3]] ]
```

How can i unzip this so that I have the following output list in Python:

```
[ [[John],[Student],[1]], [[Sam],[Athlete],[2]],[[Jack],[Teacher],[3]] ]
```

Essentially what I want is for the items with the 0th index in all the sublists to be together and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: In Python these are lists, not arrays.

Comment: Why is each element nested in another list? I.e. why `["John"]` instead of just `"John"`?

Comment: One way of doing this is apply a filter on the initial list say A to get a list of subarrays matching a certain len. Also @Barmar's question is valid. Why all elements are lists?

Comment: All valid questions but I cant provide the data im working with. If I could it would make a lot more sense. But hank you @Barmar the transpose list of lists technique worked!